# Unable to remove permission of pem file using git bash

Tags: ssh

I want to change the permission of my .pem file.

Applied:

```
$chmod -c 600 mykey
```

It gives me result like new

```
-------
```

but after this, if I run command `ls -l`, the result is

```
-rw-r--r
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git Bash on Windows you won't be able to use chmod. The underlying filesystem works different as it is Windows.